# SensorManager, the if and else of the same condition are executed at the same time

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager, proximitysensor

while I was debugging the code posted below, I decided to place a `Toast` in the body of the `if`statement and in the body of the `else` statement, so I can see where the error comes from. When I ran the app I found the both `Toasts` are executed. initially the `Toast` within the `if` statement shows and and after few seconds the display switches to the `Toast` within the `else` statement and they keep alternating. I do not know how a condition is evaluated to be true and and false at the same time. Please provide logical explanation and suggestions to solve this problem.

JavaCode:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        accelerometerValues = event.values.clone();
        tvAcc_XReading.setText(Float.toString(accelerometerValues[0]));
        tvAcc_YReading.setText(Float.toString(accelerometerValues[1]));
        tvAcc_ZReading.setText(Float.toString(accelerometerValues[2]));
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        magnetometerValues = event.values.clone();
        tvMagneto_XReading.setText(Float.toString(magnetometerValues[0]));
        tvMagneto_YReading.setText(Float.toString(magnetometerValues[1]));
        tvMagneto_ZReading.setText(Float.toString(magnetometerValues[2]));
    }
    if (accelerometerValues != null && magnetometerValues != null) {
        float [] matrixR = new float[9];
        float [] matrixI = new float[9];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(matrixR, matrixI, accelerometerValues, 
                magnetometerValues);
        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            float [] orientationMatrix = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(matrixR, orientationMatrix);
            tvAzimuthReading.setText(Float.toString(orientationMatrix[0]));
            tvPitchReading.setText(Float.toString(orientationMatrix[1]));
            tvRollReading.setText(Float.toString(orientationMatrix[2]));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Rmatrix", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a break statement to your cases, otherwise it will fall through.

```
switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        accelerometerValues = event.values.clone();
        tvAcc_XReading.setText(Float.toString(accelerometerValues[0]));
        tvAcc_YReading.setText(Float.toString(accelerometerValues[1]));
        tvAcc_ZReading.setText(Float.toString(accelerometerValues[2]));
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
        magnetometerValues = event.values.clone();
        tvMagneto_XReading.setText(Float.toString(magnetometerValues[0]));
        tvMagneto_YReading.setText(Float.toString(magnetometerValues[1]));
        tvMagneto_ZReading.setText(Float.toString(magnetometerValues[2]));
        break;
    }
```

Comment: initially, the toast within the else statement executes, and after few seconds the other one within if statements runs. but this time after adding break statement, no alternation